# C# lower quality for JPEG image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm trying to make an console application in .net core 3, this application can successfully get a bitmap from the computer and send it to another computer. But now I want to lower the quality of the image and send it as a JPEG file.

I have looked on the internet but I'm unable to get it to work. My latest attempt I tried to use the following [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-set-jpeg-compression-level) website. But with this approach I get stuck at `ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);` since my application cannot find `GetEncoder`. I have found `GetEncoder` in `System.Text.Encoding.Getencoding` but here `getEncoder` doesn't take any parameters.

So my question is which namespace do I have to use or is there another way to lower the quality of an JPEG image?

Comment: Have a look  [.NET Core Image Processing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-image-processing/)

Comment: You should read the whole example: `GetEncoder` is an addition function that is described on the same page.

Comment: @Filburt clearly I'm blind.... I have read that page many times and havent seen that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my functions to compress image as jpeg

```
    public static System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

        foreach (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static byte[] GetCompressedImage(System.Drawing.Image img, long quality)
    {
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo ici = GetEncoder(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters eps = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(2);
        eps.Param[0] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
        eps.Param[1] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderValue.CompressionLZW);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, ici, eps);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```